# Am I using the set/get function wrong?

Tags: c#, class

There is this problem which I need to solve in my program which is about the get/set function.

HERE IS THE FULL UNEDITED CODE: https://pastebin.com/Vd8zC51m

EDIT: My good friend found the solution, which was to use "value" like so:

```
        {
            get
            {
                return this.returnValue;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value > 30)
                {
                    this.returnValue = value - (value * 0.10f);
                } else
                {
                    this.returnValue = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

I'M SORRY IF I WASTED ANYONES TIME...!

The problem goes like this:
Make a Price attribute which returns the price reduced by 10% if it's over 30 using set/get.

What I'm getting:
Value of 0.

I know what's wrong, I just don't know how to fix it. I know it's in the set command.
After I show the code, you might have a better understanding.

I've tried searching around the internet how to use the set command correctly and tried different ways of doing the set command.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name;
    public string writerName;
    public string bPublisher;
    public float bPrice;
    public string bTheme;
    public float returnValue;

    public Book(string name, string writer, string publisher, float price, string theme)
    {
        Name = name;
        writerName = writer;
        bPublisher = publisher;
        bPrice = price;
        bTheme = theme;
    }

    public float Price
    {
        get
        {
            return returnValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.bPrice > 30)
            {
                returnValue = this.bPrice - (this.bPrice * 0.10f);
            } else
            {
                returnValue = this.bPrice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----------These are the main parts cut from the program----------------------

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Book k2 = new Book("A book", "O. Writer", "Publisher Ab", 36.90f, "Fantasy");
    Console.WriteLine(k2.Price);
}
```

Comment: Doing this sort of calculation in a setter is a little smelly and unpredictable (even if its not the problem)

Comment: what is `palautus` ? it is not declared in the class?=!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you put the logic into the getter. It seems to make more sense since you don't use `value` in the setter:

```
public float Price
{
    get
    {
        if (this.bPrice > 30)
        {
            return this.bPrice - (this.bPrice * 0.10f);
        } 
        else
        {
            return this.bPrice;
        }
    }

    private set
    {
        this.bPrice = value
    }
}
```

EDIT:

a short version of the getter would look like this and (thanks to Patrick Hofman) you can calculate the 90% by multiplication with 0.9:

```
return this.bPrice > 30? this.bPrice * 0.90f : this.bPrice;


public float Price
{
    get { return this.bPrice > 30? this.bPrice * 0.90f : this.bPrice; }

    private set { this.bPrice = value; }        
}
```

I made the setter private. Remove it if you want to allow the setting/manipulation of the price also after the creation of your `Book` object.

Comment: `return this.bPrice * 0.90f;`

Comment: This (with Patrick Hofman's suggestion), when I read "*which **returns** the price reduced by 10% if...*" I automatically think **getter**

Comment: I apologize for the unclear text, I am a beginner myself. Thank you a lot for this help and dedication!

Comment: @fibershot. you are welcome. Your explanation was not unclear. I understood it quite well. But you really should consider the comment by Rafalon and use the getter to return the modified value as I did in my answer. I just saw your edit and you are still using the setter there in your solution

Answer (score 7):

So we have *two* prices here: *net* (e.g. `45.00`) and *reduced* price (`45.00 - 4.50 == 41.50`)

```
public Book {
  ...
  const Decimal PriceThreshold = 30.0m;
  const Decimal ReducePerCent = 10.0m; 

  private Decimal m_NetPrice;

  // Net price
  // Decimal (not Single, Double) usually is a better choice for finance
  public Decimal NetPrice {
    get {
      return m_NetPrice;
    }
    set {
      if (value < 0) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value));

      m_NetPrice = value;
    }
  }  

  // Price with possible reduction
  public Decimal Price {
    get {
      return NetPrice > PriceThreshold 
        ? NetPrice - NetPrice / 100.0m * ReducePerCent
        : NetPrice;
    } 
  } 
}
```

Please, note that we *don't have* `set` for `Price` property; there's *ambiguity* since one `Price`, say, `28.80` corresponds to *two* valid `NetPrice`s (`28.80` or `32.00`: `32.00 - 3.20 == 28.80`)

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the Setter to set the price. Try the below.

```
 public Book(string name, string writer, string publisher, float price, string theme)
        {
            Name = name;
            writerName = writer;
            bPublisher = publisher;
            Price = price; // use the setter here, not the member variable 
            bTheme = theme;
        }
```

If you make the below private, then you will additional protection from people using the wrong variables

```
private string Name;
private string writerName;
private string bPublisher;
private float bPrice;
private string bTheme;
private float returnValue;
```

You should also consider making your price a decimal to avoid floating point precision errors.

And as per comment, you need to do a little more work on your property

```
 public float Price
        {
            get
            {
                return bPrice;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value > 30)
                {
                    bPrice = value - (value * 0.10);
                } 
                else
                {
                    bPrice = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Then it still doesn't work. OP uses too many variables to write values to in the property itself.

Comment: "You should also consider making your price a double to avoid floating point precision errors." Then you should use `decimal`. `double` still has fp issues.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need to set the `Price` in the Book constructor as below:

```
public Book(string name, string writer, string publisher, float price, string theme)
    {
        Name = name;
        writerName = writer;
        bPublisher = publisher;
        Price = price; 
        bTheme = theme;
    }
```

And then in the setter of the `Price` you can do it like this:

```
public float Price
    {
        get
        {
            return returnValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value > 30)
            {
                returnValue = value - (value * 0.10f);
            }
            else
            {
                palautus = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not talking about plagiarism. I am talking about the value of 2 answers that tell the same thing. Can you tell me what is the qualitative difference between your answer and the answer by Murray?